# CQ5 fails to load and execute ReauireJS module that runs on CQ6

Tags: javascript, requirejs, aem

I created a drag able component that what it does, is to require a certain module using **RequireJS**, and then executing this module. When I try to drag and use this component on **CQ5**, it fails to load, but on **CQ6** it works fine!

> edit1: CQ5 refers to **localhost:4502/cf#/content/somePage.html** url whereas CQ6 refers to
>   **localhost:4502/editor.html/content/somePage.html**
>
> edit2: I tried to use more simpler component the depends on **jQuery,
>   Backbone and underscore**. It failed to execute because of binding
>   issue. I am trying to find now where CQ5 client code corrupting it.
>   Any help with that will be helpful!

One thing I saw, is that if I am adding the **forceChannel query param**, it loads the component, but fails to load the parsys fields. It also show the following error multiple time in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined
```

It happens when it try to execute the following expression:

```
CQ.WCM.edit
```

Does anyone familiar with that issue? Or maybe show me where specifically might be the problem.

Thanks :)